# ArcGauge functionality in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am trying to implement an ArcGauge that changes with my dataset and I cannot seem to find any examples of an ArcGauge being used this way on any of Telerik's demos.  I want it to automatically update when my database is filled.

I want to have it function like other Kendo components where you pass a model in and then it functions based on that model.  I do not see any way to pass a model into the ArcGauge.

Telerik's Demo code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ArcGauge()
        .Name("gauge")
        .Value(65)
        .Scale(x => x.Min(0).Max(100))
        .CenterTemplate("#:value#%")
)
```

I want to add

```
.ArcGauge<Model>()
```

And then call upon the mode in the value

```
.Value(model => model.Data)
```

I am wondering if there is another way to do this.  It appears that this is a functionality of the Angular version of Arc Gauges but I want to do it in asp.net MVC.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you pass a model into the view you can then call the model and get any data that is attached to it.  You do not have to technically pass a model into the gauge you can call the model from the view.

```
.Value(Model.SomeNumber)
```